# TCPDF Cell text uppercase and color change

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf, whmcs

I have an TCPDF file where i want to set 1 cell with fill-background color, and to change the text in that cell to Upper-Case and color to white

```
$pdf->SetFont($pdfFont, 'B', 10);
$pdf->SetFillColor(59,78,135);
$pdf->Cell(50, 6, Lang::trans('supportticketsclient'), 0, 1, 'L', true);
```

I know i have to add "strtoupper" for uppercase letters but don't know where, and SetTextColor or something similar to it, but when i set that

```
$pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,0);
```

My whole pdf color is changed.

Answer (score 3):

you just need to use the same function to change the colour back to the original(or a new colour)

```
$pdf->SetFont($pdfFont, 'B', 10);
$pdf->SetFillColor(59,78,135);
$pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,0);
$pdf->Cell(50, 6, strtoupper(Lang::trans('supportticketsclient')), 0, 1, 'L', true);
$pdf->SetTextColor(255,255,255);//change back to black
```

Comment: Okey the color its okey now, but UpperCase its not working :(

Comment: what does `Lang::trans('supportticketsclient')` return?

Comment: Translated word "Client" <- that i wanted to be "CLIENT"

Comment: sure should work, but you could try `$txt=strtoupper(Lang::trans('supportticketsclient'));$pdf->Cell(50, 6,$txt, 0, 1, 'L', true);`

Comment: if that fails, `echo strtoupper(Lang::trans('supportticketsclient'));` see if that works.

Comment: It doesnt work either way... i guess i would have to change the word in php-translate file to CLIENT :) (but that way everywhere in the program client will be with capitalized letters)

Comment: you could, but should not have to, its weird it is not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93985/discussion-between-viktorg-and-dagon).

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem on changing the text in a cell to Upper-Case..

What I did was convert it on my query

```
$appName = $row['appFname']." ".$row['appMname']. " ".$row['appLname'];
$appNameUPPER = strtoupper($appName);
```

then I used that variable on my cell

```
$pdf->Cell(179,26,''.$appNameUPPER.'', 'B','', 'C', '','','','','','B');
```

then it works! Try converting it on your query~

It's my first time to answer here hope it works on you (^_^)/